# Как взять значение с input в javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/dracula_graffle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/dracula_graph.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/dracula_algorithms.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="classes.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
      overflow: hidden;
      }
        #text{
            text-align:right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="text">
    <input type="text" id="11" size="10">
    <input type="text" id="12" size="10">
    <input type="text" id="13" size="10"><br><br>
    <input type="text" id="21" size="10">  
    <input type="text" id="22" size="10"> 
    <input type="text" id="23" size="10"><br><br>
    <input type="text" id="31" size="10"> 
    <input type="text" id="32" size="10"> 
    <input type="text" id="33" size="10"> 
    </div>
<div id="canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
//javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
    var width = $(document).width();
    var height = $(document).height()-300;
    var g = new Graph();
    g.edgeFactory.template.style.directed = true;
    var oneone=document.getElementById("11").value
    if(oneone="1"){
    g.addEdge("1","1")
    }
}
```

Comment: у вас `if(oneone="1")` вместо `if(oneone=="1")`

Answer (score 2):

Так получите значение поля `input` с айди `11`:

`alert(document.getElementById('11').value);`

Comment: как кнопку написать что бы значения отправлялося в javascript код?

Comment: JS функция:
`function fieldValue(id) { return alert('value of id ' + id + ': ' + document.getElementById(id).value); }`
Кнопка:
`<button onclick="return fieldValue(11);">Кнопка</button>`

Comment: у меня уже есть функция